# Is there any way to re-fresh or re-create a custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i have create a custom view class, this class contains three **TextViews**. I am just using this custom view in on of my Fragment layout. My layout is like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.abc.views.HeaderView
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.rfs.app.views.HeaderView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/widget54"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerView" >

       --------------------------------------
       --------------------------------------

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, HeaderView  child's updating(change text/color) when i click on button in my fragment. these changes are not reflecting instantly.

all child's are textviews in HeaderView class.

Is there any way to re-fresh or re-create this custom view?

Comment: invalidate the view!

Comment: Add the java code please

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your custom view doesn't invalidates itself correctly. Please make sure you call invalidate or postInvalidate if doing work in background thread, whenever you want your custom view to call onDraw. You can share your custom view code so that we can point out the issue here.